# Expressões regulares postgresql

Tags: postgresql, regex, trigger, psql

Fala pessoal, preciso de uma ajuda

Estou tentando fazer uma trigger no postgresql que verifica se o formato de um novo dado a ser inserido em uma tabela está em um determinado formato, no caso, o formato de telefone.

Preciso que o novo telefone a ser inserido esteja no formato `+pp(dd)nnnnn-nnnn`

Meu problema se encontra na verificação do formato, atualmente está assim `NEW.telefone LIKE '^+([^0-9]{2}[^)][^0-9]{5}[^-][^0-9]{4}'`

Sou novato com expressões regulares e estou meio perdido, poderiam me ajudar com essa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui solucionar o problema aqui, estava montando a expressão regular de maneira errada, aqui está a maneira correta

`NEW.telefone ~ '^\+[0-9]{2}\([0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{5}\-[0-9]{4}$'`